# Make a git-alias or similar that includes "branchfolder/" - part of the branch name

Tags: git, git-branch, git-alias

I just recently discovered how to make git aliases, which are great, but I was wondering if there is a way to include my common branch prefix with the alias. So what I would like is something like:

Alias in .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    br = checkout -b branchfolder/
```

and then beeing able to use the command like

```
$ git br newbranch
```

to call

```
git checkout -b branchfolder/newbranch
```

This, of course, is not what happens, as the command translates to

```
git checkout -b branchfolder/ newbranch
```

and I get an error where git asking:

> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'branchfolder/' at the same
>   time. Did you intend to checkout 'newbranch' which can not be resolved as
>   commit?

How would I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[alias]
    br = "!sh -c 'git checkout -b branchfolder/$0'"
```

I would advise you to use `-t` instead of `-b` though.

Comment: *Why* is `-t` better than `-b` in this case? It would be great if you could explain this in your answer, instead of making noobs like me search for the information themselves :P Some links to/quotes from the Git docs would be even more appreciated ;-)